# Adding ImageView to a RelativeLayout Causes a Runtime Exception

Tags: android

I am trying to create a widget that displays items parsed form an XML file file.  In the end, an image, a title, and URL of the original item are going to be displayed.  But, now that I am working on the layout, I am getting a runtime error after adding the `ImageView` to its container.  The `<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/newsdviewlayout"` is inside the root View (which is a `RelativeLayout`) for the main layout.  Help please.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/newsdviewlayout"
   style="@style/newsviewstyle"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsviewimg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: An error log is the magic sauce for a question to get the best answers :-)

Comment: @Ravi Vyas  The error log was not showing me anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I think you miss the required attribute `android:layout_width=""` and `android:layout_height=""`, so for your case, the xml will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsdviewlayout"
    style="@style/newsviewstyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/newsviewimg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Or as for the `RelativeLayout` you can also put that 2 attribute inside your `newsviewstyle` style.

Comment: Silly mistakes taking my time again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` for both RelativeLayout as well as the ImageView.